# getting-started vs beginner (RIP)

Tags: discussion, tags

I was about to tag a question as [getting-started](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/getting-started). But the description suggested that [beginner](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) would be more appropriate. The tricky part is that no such tag exists. Should we add the beginner tag, or should we modify the description of getting-started?

I'd suggest the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag [beginner](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) was deleted by a mod in regards to [Why do we have a [beginner] tag?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1610/23159)

As such it has already been established that we don't want the tag to exist, which means we should update the wiki of the tag [getting-started](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/getting-started). I removed the reference to the tag [beginner](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) from the tag wiki of [getting-started](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/getting-started).

As for the question you wanted to post on main / edit on main: [beginner](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) was removed because it was a meta tag that doesn't convey anything about the content of the question, but only about the personal level of experience of the question author, therefore you should try to add tags related to what the person in the question is trying to write / having trouble with. That will get the attention of the experts, whereas [beginner](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) would only get the attention of people who want to help out beginners - which is pretty broad and wouldn't be as helpful as just getting the experts for the type of work and the problem area the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "Getting Started" means "in the day" or "in the project."  Example: for every single book, Terry Pratchett, Margaret Atwood, and Michael Chrichton had to *get started*.  Maybe it's from random notes and beginning to turn things into a plot, maybe it's opening a new file and typing, maybe it's doing pre-writing, or arranging for someone to transcribe the dictation.

Also, every day that they wrote (whether it was truly a daily thing or whatever their work habits were), they had to also *get started.*  It may be about tea and a new pen, or rereading the previous writing, or setting a timer -- whatever ritual or procedure indicates Writing Now.

But as far as becoming a writer, they only were beginners early on.  While "Getting Started" *might* refer to a career-phase, I feel that other tags (such as "first book" "first-time-author" or even "beginner") match that more.  I don't feel that Getting Started is a great synonym for Beginner.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was focusing on the beginner aspect but you're absolutely correct.  [tag:getting-started] is for starting a project, not a career.

Answer (score -1):

We *do* have a beginner tag.

[first-time-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-time-author)

> Use this tag for questions specifically about issues encountered by
>   authors writing or publishing their first work. DO NOT use this tag
>   simply because you are a first time author.
>
> First time authors face different challenges in both writing their
>   works and getting them published than established authors. This tag is
>   meant to collect those questions, giving first time authors an easy
>   way to search for the answers they need.

Perhaps "beginner" should be added as a synonym to  [first-time-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-time-author) to make it easier to find?

Comment: We should probably get rid of that tag, too, as it's a meta-tag just like [tag:beginner] was.

Comment: @Secespitus It's not super common but it is a tag that gets used now and then.  I wonder if it would be more popular if it were easier to find.  It comes from before my time but I do retag to it occasionally.

Comment: Popularity is irrelevant for this discussion. Important is what the tag is about and how it will help connect experts with people who are having questions. Look at the [guidance for tags](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), which explicitly mentions [beginner] as not being a useful tag. Also[The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: "If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag. For example, the meaning of the tag [subjective] is, itself, subjective; the same is true for tags like [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? Use only tags that have a broadly accepted, objective definition."